# How to input 2 integers in one line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, line

I wonder if it is possible to input two or more integer numbers in one line of standard input. In `C`/`C++` it's easy:

`C++`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    return 0;
}
```

`C`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
}
```

In `Python`, it won't work:

```
enedil@notebook:~$ cat script.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
enedil@notebook:~$ python3 script.py 
3 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 5'
```

So how to do it?

Comment: @Asad yes it would.  why wouldn't it?

Comment: @Asad what compiiler do you use? I have `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`. It works. Very well.

Comment: @RyanHaining There's a space there. I'm no C expert, but I don't think that would work unless the input was `35`. edit: Just looked up `scanf`, guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Asad it works with a space, not without. Compile it yourself and test.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Split the entered text on whitespace:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

Demo:

```
>>> a, b = map(int, input().split())
3 5
>>> a
3
>>> b
5
```

Comment: +1. This is the nice example of why `map` and the like functions should remain in Python 3. I would only add the `, *rest` to the left side to make it more robust. The non-map version with the list comprehension is also possible, but it is not that clean: `a, b, *rest = [int(e) for e in input().split()]`.

Comment: `input()` still didn't work for me in Pycharm ( Python 2.7 ). Change it to `raw_input` to make it work.

Comment: @blumonkey: this question is about Python 3. For Python 2, you indeed need to use `raw_input`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is it possible to take the same inputs from multi lines? Something like `a, b = map(int, input().split("\n"))` ?

Comment: @deppfx: `input()` can't take multiple lines. Use a loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how to use the split() function in the list?

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi: I'm not sure what you are asking. `str.split()` is a string method, if you have a list of strings, then you need a loop (either an explicit `for` loop over the list, or a list comprehension).

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can i use split() function inside the loop?

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi: that's too broad to answer in comments, because it depends entirely on what you are splitting and what you are doing with the values. Perhaps you can do some research on this with searching Stack Overflow? There are many, many questions and answers on the subject here.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Python 2, then the answer provided by Martijn does not work. Instead,use:

```
a, b = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Comment: Sorry guy, the tag said "python 3". Your code is valid in Python 2. input in py3 is exactly raw_input from py2.

Answer (score 0):

```
x,y = [int(v) for v in input().split()]
print("x : ",x,"\ty: ",y)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, every time we use `input()` function it directly switches to the next line. To use multiple inline inputs, we have to use `split()` method along with `input` function by which we can get desired output.

```py
a, b = [int(z) for z in input().split()]
print(a, b)
```

Input:

```sh
3 4
```

Output:

```sh
3 4
```

Answer (score -2):

```
x, y = int(input()),  int(input())
print("x : ",x,"\ty: ",y)
```

Comment: This prompts for input *in 2 separate lines*. The question was entering 2 integers in 1 line.

Comment: it is asking for one line of input not one line of code :)